# ImportError: cannot import name 'count_hi' from 'countstring'

Tags: python-3.x, import, python-import

I have two .py files. When I try to run starting.py it just says "ImportError: cannot import name 'count_hi' from 'countstring' (C:\Users\suspended.mirror\PycharmProjects\blankpage\venv\countstring.py)". How can I get it to run?

I've tried various variations of renaming the import, adding .py, ensuring both .py files are in the same directory but still wrong apparently.

**starting.py**

```
from countstring import count_hi

count_hi("testhi")
```

countstring.py

```
class countstring:

    def count_hi(str):
        k = 0
        i = 0
        n = 0
        is_hi = ""
        hi_count = 0

        while k < (len(str) - 1):
            first_letter = str[0 + i]
            second_letter = str[1 + n]
            is_hi = first_letter + second_letter
            i += 1
            n += 1
            k += 1
            if is_hi == "hi":
                hi_count += 1

        print(hi_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python needs to know which directory that module is in. Try using a relative import:

```py
from .countstring import count_hi
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out myself.

The second module countstring.py didn't need the "class countstring:" at the top. I don't know why that is but possibly because that module wasn't creating an object. It was just defining a function.